# GDAL Image Dependency via Docker or Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gdal

I am trying to figure out Docker and/or Docker Compose settings in order to add the GDAL libraries or container image dependency within my sample/test application so that I can execute GDAL commands via bin/bash within my console and eventually a web application boxed within their own Docker container.

Right now, I have a console application that I am attempting to run that I need to have a dependency on an existing Docker image: geodata/gdal:ubuntu-full-3.2.0.

I currently have my docker compose set up as the following:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    gdal:
        image: "geodata/gdal:ubuntu-full-3.2.0"
    satellites.console:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}satellitesconsole
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Satellites.Console/Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - gdal
```

My dockerfile for the console application is just a bare bones to copy, build, and publish the console application:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Satellites.Console/Satellites.Console.csproj", "Satellites.Console/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Satellites.Console/Satellites.Console.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Satellites.Console"
RUN dotnet build "Satellites.Console.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Satellites.Console.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Satellites.Console.dll"]
```

From my understanding, that GDAL container image should contain, and install, all the required pieces to use the GDAL library within it's container.  I want to bring those dependencies and over with my console application so I can run bin/bash to run against the GDAL libraries.  I was hoping to be able to achieve this via something along the lines of this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = "/bin/bash", Arguments = @"gdalinfo --version", RedirectStandardOutput = true, UseShellExecute = false };
Process proc = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, };
proc.Start();
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
System.Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Am I going about this the correct way?

I've tried everything from the current settings to copying the Dockerfile from the source repo to try and install everything within my console container (I think I need the .sh files that are included there to get it to install this way, but I have no idea of what to do with those, since running the build for it doesn't appear to do any installations or anything).  No matter what approach I've used, I am not getting any luck running the bash from the console application, I get the

> /bin/bash: gdalinfo: No such file or directory

meaning either it's not installing the dependencies, or the PATHS aren't getting setup correctly.

Has anyone tried and succeeded in setting their Docker container environment up this way before?  Being new to how Docker and the containers work, I'm sort of lost at this point.

Comment: You need to include that image name in your Dockerfile somewhere.  Note that there's no way to merge images, so if you need to use the .Net images you might need to figure out how to install the GDAL libraries on top of them.  If you specify both `build:` and `image:` in the `docker-compose.yml`, it builds the image from the Dockerfile and gives it that name; it doesn't actually use the corresponding Docker Hub image at all.

Comment: How would I make the call then as if I was running it from the GDAL image from the .NET container?

I've tried getting it to compile the GDAL libraries as part of my .NET container, but getting it to not skip over the steps has been challenging.  I had to re-copy my pieces and it's still not running/installing correctly.

Comment: If your final image needs to be `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime`, it can't use that other image with the GDAL libraries preinstalled at all.  (If your language had a lighter-weight runtime, you could potentially do something like install Python and Flask on top of the GDAL image and provide an HTTP facade, but I suspect that won't match your existing application setup well.)

Comment: The only reason I did that was b/c I was familiar with .NET Core, which can be ran from any system from my understanding, and was just going to use a ASP.Core web service.  I am pretty flexible with what I can stand up, I'll just need to eventually end up with a rest based service.  I thought I'd be able to either copy my runtime/service into the GDAL, or vice versa to get things setup correctly.  I'm trying to take the Dockerfile from the GDAL and basically bake that in to my service or console container now, not sure if that's going to work or not.